# Zabbix preprocessing Обрезать конец строчки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, zabbix

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Preprocessing Обрезать конец строчки, до значения МАС? У меня по SNMP выбирается OID, который показывает например

SN:111111 MAC: ******* IP:

Из всей строчки мне нужен только SN и то только цифры его. Впереди я отрезал leftTrim символы SN:, а как вырезать всё, что начинается с МАС и до конца строки?

Comment: `(?<=SN:)\d+` https://regex101.com/r/nqdGPD/1 В Википедии подробно разбираются регулярные выражения, обратите внимание на просмотр вперед и назад - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%91%D0%B4_%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4.

Answer (score 0):

Для этой операции не нужны регулярные выражения.Там же в пред обработке,найдите "обрезать справа" и "обрезать с лева" и и прям укажите текст или символы которые требуется обрезать. В вашем случае это будет так:
обрезать слева: SN:
обрезать с права: MAC: ******* IP: